# Правильное написание: "с ней" или "с нею"?

Tags: орфография, грамотная-речь

Уточните, пожалуйста, какое написание верно: "с ней" или "с нею"?

Answer (score 2):

Возможны оба варианта. Причем в стилистическом отношении они равноправны.

Answer (score 1):

*"С нею"* чаще используется в литературном языке (например, в поэзии для сохранения размера строк), а *"с ней"* - в обычной речи, хотя оба варианта можно использовать где угодно.

Answer (score 1):

В принципе всё верно, но "с нею" мне кажется архаичным вариантом.

Answer (score 0):

"С нею" - этот вариант, мне кажется, предпочтительнее. Почему? Потому что существуют другие созвучия: "к ней", "в ней" и т. д., которые однозначны. Предлагаемое же написание имеет два варианта, и следует избегать типичной нашей русской неоднозначности. Да и просто " с нею" звучит музыкальнее, звучнее. "Вдруг - перед нею дверь стоит!" "Перед ней возникла дверь". Я чувствую музыкальную разницу между двумя фразами. А вы - не чувствуете? И там и там стихотворная фраза, но первая - экспрессивна, а вторая скучна, равнодушна, безэмоциональна. Даже противу грамматики я - за экспрессию.

Comment: Ссылаться на созвучные варианты "к ней", "в ней", на мой взгляд, не стоит, поскольку это другие падежные формы.

Comment: Я соглашусь с Вами, потому что более Вы не выразили никаких отрицательных оценок (а они наверняка в душе у Вас напрашивались!). Но, извините, править ответ не стану, поскольку всем видно Ваше замечание, и, если я исправлю свой текст, оно повиснет в воздухе в виде НЛО, будоража благочестивые умы коллег своим неожиданным и необъяснимым появлением.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, что оба варианта верны.

Comment: «Более устаревшим» ======== Значит оба устарели?

Answer (score 0):

Личное местоимение **ОНА** (женский род) в творительном падеже (**с кем?**) имеет **две абсолютно равноправные** формы: **с ней** и **с нею** — так сложилось в языке.

*Должно быть, усталость и недосып сыграли **с ней** злую шутку.*

*Пророчества Марии Ленорман сбывались и сыграли **с нею** злую шутку в конце жизни.*

[Склонение личных местоимений по падежам](https://www.ruspeach.com/learning/13186/)

Answer (score 0):

Зависит от значения, от сути высказывания. Пример. 
"Бороться с ней за правду" - с ней, но против кого-то: 1) действуем отдельно друг от друга (может не зная друг друга), у нас с ней не совместные действия; 2) вместе с ней и совместно решая вопросы по борьбе с кем-то. 
"Бороться с нею за правду" - с нею самой: 1) против неё, она противник; 2) бороться с кем-то другим, но имея её в своём сердце.

Comment: Оба варианта, при желании, можно понять в значении "бороться против нее".

Comment: При желании можно смешивать и глаголы "одеть", "надеть".

Comment: Странно видеть ответ без аргументов и ссылок на седьмом году обсуждения.